# Laravel nova - How to remove required validation from BelongsTo relationship?

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

I have a Nova resource named "Partner" with relationship to another Nove resource named "Rate".

```
BelongsTo::make('Rate*', 'customrate', 'App\Nova\Rate')->onlyOnForms()
```

Now when user try to create a parter, the select field to choose rate is mandatory.

Client doesn`t want to keep it mandatory to choose a rate for partner. Any solution for this problem?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use `nullable()` which is added in version 1.1.7

```
BelongsTo::make('Rate*', 'customrate', 'App\Nova\Rate')
    ->onlyOnForms()
    ->nullable()
```